# How to determine operator placement

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

I am confused about placement of operators:
Given:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2];
```

So far as I can tell, each of the following is correct:

```
var len = a.length;
var lastElt = a.pop();
var str = String(a);
var typeStr = typeof a;
```

Is there an easy way to remember/think about whether the operator goes before or after the operand and whether it requires parentheses? Or is it simply rote memorization?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what it is that you're confused about. What do you mean by "operator" here? When learning a programming language, there are indeed many things that you simply have to memorize.

Comment: Those are mostly not operators.

Comment: you need to learn this. basically operators have no parentheses and function/methods have ones. classes have one if used with parameter/s.

Comment: property, method, global object, operator

Comment: Thanks for all the prompt replies.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go:

**case #1**

`var len = a.length;`

In this case you're calling the method `lenght` of the array store in the variable `a`.

**case #2**

`var lastElt = a.pop();`

As before, here you're calling the method `pop` of the array.

**case #3**

`var str = String(a);`

You aren't not calling any array's method. Here you're casting the array. i.e. you are stringifying the array.

**case #4**

`var typeStr = typeof a;`

Here you also aren't calling any array's method. You are calling the `typeof` method of the window object and passing the array `a` as an argument.

As you can see. In the first two cases, you are calling array's methods. In the last two cases, you are calling window object's methods and passing your array as an argument.

Comment: `length` is a property, not a method. a method would require parentheses.

Comment: Good observation @NinaScholz. Thanks.

Comment: `typeof` is an unary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your list there mostly consists of things that are **not** operators:

- [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is a `property` belonging to `Array` objects. It returns the number of items in the `Array`.
- [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) is a `method` belonging to `Array` objects. It removes the last item from the `Array` and retuns it.
- [`String()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is a global object which is the `constructor` for a `String` object. It takes any object as a parameter and converts it to a `String`
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) **is** an operator. It returns a string that indicates the type of the subsequent operand.

For more reference, here is some information about [JavaScript operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

I highly recommend searching Google for some beginning JavaScript tutorials so you can learn the basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the prompt replies. In reply to the question 'What do you mean by "operator" here?' I come from a background of mathematics and (lately) c programming. By "operator" I wanted to speak abstractly about anything that mapped its argument to something useful, using it to include methods, properties, etc., without enumerating them. My attempt to abstract these is probably the source of my confusion. I now understand that what is required is rote memorization, something like declensions in Latin ;-).

Answer (score -1):

Operators refer to +,=*,/ etc.

I don't think there is an easy way to remember. If it is a 'property', there will be no parentheses. If it is a function, there will be parentheses. I always remember that length is a property of an array, and that push and pop are actions you can do to the array. Type casting always starts with the 'type' capitalized followed by what you want casted in the parenthesis. typeof is just a weird one.